# Disable access to EndPoints - Spring boot + Google OAuth app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I need some guidance here. I have a Spring boot app with a few api's. I have configured OAuth Client. When I try to access an endpoint, I am redirected to google's login page. After I provide the login details, I am redirected back and the api gets executed and returns whatever data.

At this point, i want to validate if a user x is already in my local database. If not, i want to throw and exception saying x has to register first before he can access the api.
I have the below code in the SecurityConfig class and a custom UserDetailsService.

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                /* Add any additional roles or authorities here */
                Collections.emptyList()
        );
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig -

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests
                            // .antMatchers("/register", "/oauth/callback").permitAll() // Allow public access to registration and callback endpoints
                            .anyRequest().authenticated() // Require authentication for all other requests
            )
            .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());
            // .formLogin(withDefaults()); // Use default form-based login

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(
            org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                    .username("user")
                    .password("password")
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build()
    );
}
}
```

I want to know how to correctly use the MyUserDetailsService in the SecurityConfig class. Thanks for any help and guidance.